# sqlite3 Python: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

При работе с sqlite3 на Python, возникла вот такая вот ошибка, что я якобы передаю 3 аргумента, а указываю 2.

[image: Ошибка]

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

title = [['Приехали гости'], ['Уехали гости']]
img = [['url=1'], ['url=2']]

def add_db(title, img):
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title, img) VALUES (?, ?)", title, img)

add_db(title, img)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Если же я передаю один аргумент для одного столбца, то все нормально записывается в БД без ошибок.

```
def add_db(title):
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title) VALUES (?)", title)

add_db(title)
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно помню, множественные аргументы нужно передавать кортежем:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title, img) VALUES (?, ?)", (title, img))
```

Comment: При написании данного кода  `c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title, img) VALUES (?, ?)", (title, img))`  я получаю следующую ошибку: **sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.**